# My adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() is not working

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

How to update an ArrayAdapter with my new array?

Belwo is my ArrayAdapter with a default array added to it.

```
String[] array_spinner = new String[]{"Select your state."};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,array_spinner);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.state_spinner_layout);
Myspinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now I load some JSON data that parses the info into the `array_spinner_data` and I want to call notifyDataSetChanged()

```
array_spinner = new String[]jsonArray.length(); 


        for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
        {   
            String styleValue = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i).getString(0);    
            Log.d(TAG, styleValue);
            array_spinner[i] = styleValue;

        }
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(array_spinner.length));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I am not seeing any errors and all of my Log.d are coming back as they should. But when I click my spinner all that is showing is the original `Select your state`  I left out some of the basic onCreate and Json load stuff but if anyone needs to see it just let me know.

Comment: Your are putting the data into `array_spinner` not `spinner_data`

Comment: That was my fault they should all be array_spinner I was testing something.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`notifyDataSetChanged` is "not working" because you are not changing the data set, you are creating a new copy, one that the adapter has no knowledge about. Use a `List<>` instead of an array, and modify **that** same list object that you passed to your adapter and it will work. If you want to keep your current code, then you have to create a new adapter over the new data set and apply it to your spinner.

Comment: in the ref guide it says notifyDataSetChanged tells the adapter that the data has changed and to refresh. If I am changing the array values doesnt that count as a change?

Comment: @Denoteone: Because you are not changing the array values, you are changing the values in a separate different array the adapter doesn't even know about.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to do t with my code above lets say without using a List? Thanks so far for the info +1

Comment: @Denoteone: If you don't want to use a `List<>`, you cant use `notifyDataSetChanged` since you are actually growing the size of the array and that is not supported. Instead you have to call `setAdapter` again with a new adapter made with the newly created array.

Comment: Thanks again. I guess I will use the List<> and try and figure it out.

Comment: @Denoteone: It's not that hard, you use a `List< String >` and keep it around (as a class member, for instance). After adding the new elements to the list, you simply call `notifiyDataSetChanged`.

Answer (score 1):

don't create a new list, 
clear the existing list then call notifydatasetchanged

```
someArrayList.clear();
someArrayList.add("element 1");
someArrayList.add("element 2");
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

- First create a list
- Before reload the list every time with new value you have to clear the existing valuea
- At last use your DataAdapter.notifyDatachanged(). function

  ```
  private Spinner spinnerTest;
  ArrayList<String> list_spinnerTest = new ArrayList<String>();

  list_spinnerTest.clear();

  String[] NameArray=new String []{"Load From Array","bbbbbbbb","cccccccccc","ddddddddd","eeeeeeeeee"};
  int count=5;
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      list_spinnerTest.add(NameArray[i]);
  }
  ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterSpinner=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list_spinnerTest);
  dataAdapterSpinner.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  spinnerTest.setAdapter(dataAdapterSpinner);

  dataAdapterSpinner.notifyDataSetChanged();
  ```